# I have a question related to laravel setup on docker-compose

Tags: laravel, docker

I want to setup a laravel environment on docker.

In a video of building a laravel environment, a centos images is created and apache and mysql are installed in it.

On the other hand, using docker-compose.yml, create an apache container and a MySQL container.

What is the difference between these?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **centOS Image**, it ***acts as a single docker component***, which includes both the web server and database.

If, You use **docker-compose**, Apache and MySQL store as ***two separate containers***.

> And It's always recommended to use **docker-compose**

Comment: Thank you for your help.
May I ask one more question?

Why is the latter recommended?

Comment: @sorasakamoto it's independent, Simple, can control access and performance

Comment: @sorasakamoto if you need sample docker-compose for Laravel, Nginx let me know